# How to look for similar emails (like / contain search) with DirectoryServices?

Tags: c#, .net, directoryservices

I am looking a way to lookup emails that contain a pattern through DirectoryServices in .NET.

```
        const ContextType contextType = ContextType.Domain;
        var principalContext = new PrincipalContext(contextType);
        var userPrincipal = new UserPrincipal(principalContext)
        {
             EmailAddress = "michelle*",
        };

        foreach (var principal in principalSearcher.FindAll().Cast<UserPrincipal>())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(principal.EmailAddress);
        }
```

If I change my code above with `EmailAddress = "*michelle*"` it won't work so I feel I can only perform a "starts with" kind of search (which is not that bad I guess...). Still I would rather like to have some "like" or "contains pattern " searches, is it possible? If so, how?

According to: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746475(v=vs.85).aspx

> Get entries containing "bob" somewhere in the common name:
>   `(cn=*bob*)`

I would have expected that the pattern could also be used for emails, is it not really the case?

[EDIT]
I want to leverage the filtering system as much as I can in order to avoid to receive too many users that I would need to filter afterwards.

Comment: do you mean you want all emails that contains the word "michelle"?

Comment: @Cyber Progs, exactly

Answer (score 0):

you can use Regular Expression as the following code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var myList = new List<string>
        {
            "a2michelle",
            "michelle",
            "michelle3f",
            "xxmichellezz",
            "noMatching",
        };
        string pattern = @"\S*michelle\S*";
        System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex regx = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(pattern);

        var matchedList = myList.Where(m => regx.IsMatch(m)).ToList();
        foreach(var match in matchedList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(match);
        }
        // end of main method
    }
```

the output is :

a2michelle
michelle
michelle3f
xxmichellezz

Comment: I would rather like to fetch directly from LDAP AD all the users that match the contain criteria instead of having an additional overhead for performing the filtering process by my application.